# mongodb ordering of a list field

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple question. In MongoDB if a have a document with the list field, does MongoDB gurantee the ordering of the values within the list.

Note: I don't care about the ordering of actual documents.

i.e. If I insert

```
{
    something: somevalue,
    alist: [1,2,3,a,s,d,f]
}
```

will the value of alist always be:

```
[1,2,3,a,s,d,f]
```

and not

```
[2,1,3,a,s,d,f] or
[1,2,3,a,s,f,d] or
...
[1,2,a,3,s,d,f] ..etc
```

Thanks,
Vackar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the array order will remain consistent as the record(s) isn't updated.